# App Store does not show my app even app is in ready for sale state

Tags: iphone, app-store, release

My app is in ready for sale state on 13th apr. 2016 but still not reflecting on app store. it's 48 hours complete. In itunes connect it showing Ready for sale and I've not set any Available date for release this version.

Comment: Verify country of iTunes. Paste a link here if you can!

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason for this can be you are in a country where your app is not available. Go to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) :

My Apps -> Select Your App -> Pricing and Availability -> Availability -> Edit

Check if your countries check box is selected. If not and you want app to be available in your country then select the check box and save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

- By default your app should be available world-wide, but it's still a valid point.
- Another issue could be that you still have to sign/agree to the distribution agreement (if it's a paid app).

It would certainly help us to answer your question, if we could get a link to your app. Is it a brand new app or an update? Also what happens, if you click on the link direct in iTunes Connect? (Under App Store Information / App Information)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolve this by make simple text change in what's new text and save it after 1-2 hours it reflect on app store.